# Reference request unital normal *-homomorphisms $B(H) \to B(K)$

Tags: reference-request, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

It is known that if $\varphi \colon B(H) \to B(K)$ is a unital non-zero normal $*$-homomorphism (for Hilbert spaces $H$ and $K$), then there exists a Hilbert space $K'$ and a unitary $U' \colon K \to H \otimes K'$ such that $\varphi(a) = U^* (a \otimes 1) U$ for all $a \in B(H)$.

More well-known is the corollary is that any unital normal $*$-isomorphism between type I von Neumann algebras is *inner*; i.e. of the form $a \mapsto U^*aU$ for some unitary $U$.

I can't find a reference for it though.  (I'm only looking for a reference, I already have a proof.)

Comment: I unfortunately don't have a reference, but I assume you want the word injective in there somewhere.

Comment: I forgot to write non-zero.  Then it’s automatically injective as its kernel is a ultraweakly closed two sided ideal and thus equal $z B(H)$ for some central projection $z$. Only choice is $z=0$

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  For some reason I thought you were trying to characterize certain unital normal completely positive maps $\phi: B(H) \rightarrow B(K)$, and I knew something was missing.  Turns out I just suck at reading.  Carry on. :)

Comment: See Theorem 5.5. of Chapter IV in Takesaki's book.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks for the reference.  That seems very close, but Takesaki writes "If $\pi$ is a normal homomorphisms of $\mathcal{M}_1$ **onto** $\mathcal{M}_2$".  If he means surjection with onto, then I don't see how this Theorem applies.

Comment: Well, $\phi$ is a normal $\ast$-homomorphism onto its image, and the image is a von Neumann algebra.

Comment: Ah, yes, now I see. Thank you.